# joining two datastes and select column form second table if there is a join

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am joining two datasets having same schema. one table is a subset of another table. I want to retain all records from the first table and get few columns from second table in case there is a join. if there are no joins then retain all columns from first table.

here is the query that i am using

```
select 
first.id,
first.date,
first.pdate,
CASE WHEN first.id = second.id then second.des else first.des end as des,
CASE WHEN first.id = second.id then second.flg else first.flg end as flg,
first.string1,
first.string2
from first left join second on first.id = second.id

first datset
1|2019-01-01|20191215|MARKET BASKET XXXXXXXX   SWXXXEY      NH|000|MARKET BASKET 00000646   SWANZEY      NH|US
2|2019-01-01|20191215|MARKET NH|000|MARKET BASKET 00000646   SWANZEY      NH|US

second dataset
1|2019-01-01|20191215|MARKET BASKET XXXXXXXX   SWANZEY      NH|000|MARKET BASKET 00000646   SWANZEY      NH|US


expected output
1|2019-01-01|20191215|MARKET BASKET XXXXXXXX   SWANZEY      NH|000|MARKET BASKET 00000646   SWANZEY      NH|US
2|2019-01-01|20191215|MARKET NH|000|MARKET BASKET 00000646   SWANZEY      NH|US
```

however this is not working as i am getting the data from first table where there is a join.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: is that a typo in the name of your second table ```from first left join seconf on first.id = second.id```, seconf instead of second?

Comment: @CarlosSR corrected the type

Comment: @GordonLinoff added sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your `CASE WHEN`, try `COALESCE`

```
COALESCE(second.des,first.des) as des,
COALESCE(second.flg,first.flg) as flg,
```

Comment: @ben . . . I don't see how this would return different results from your query.